# What's the use of search domains?

Tags: networking, dhcp

Something you often see as a configurable option for DHCP are the DNS servers and the search domain. Alright, DNS servers have an actual use, but I'm not so sure about search domains. It took me quite a bit of searching on Google to find out what they actually are.

It doesn't seem very relevant to me. Could somebody please explain what search domains are often used for and how they could possibly be useful in production?

Comment: [Difference between DHCP options 'Domain-Name' and 'Domain-Search'](http://serverfault.com/q/478915)

Comment: @DavidPostill: I'm aware of what a search domain is.

Comment: The link tells you what is does. That is why you would use it.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Again, I'm aware of what it does. I just don't understand why people would want to use it.

Comment: Try asking on http://serverfault.com/ ...

Comment: Because I don't want to type my full local domain name when accessing a server on the otherside of the room. if I want to access stuff in another domain, I need to supply one, but if I don't, it should be assumed that my query is local to my domain. that way I can type `\\files\sharename` instead of `\\files.my.local.domain.net\sharename` or `ping files` instead of `ping files.my.local.domain.net`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are typically used when there is interactive or ad-hoc access of many hosts in a subdomain, especially one with a long name, without having to type the FQDN. Makes even more sense if there are multiple subdomains, since all hosts can be accessed with a hostname.

Whether you choose to rely upon search domains in other ways (scripts, databases, programs, etc) depends on how you decide to manage your production environment.